# How to declare a variable inside bash -c

Tags: bash

I can't figure out how to declare a variable inside `bash -c` command.

```
bash -c "var=3; echo $var"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what actually happens here:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "var=3; echo $var"
+ bash -c 'var=3; echo '
```

With `set -x` you get a trace of what commands are actually executed (use `set +x` to turn this off).  Here we see that the `$var` variable is expanded to an empty string *before* the child `bash -c` shell even runs.

This is due to the double quoting of the argument to `bash -c`, which will prompt the current shell to do variable expansion within the string.  Since the `var` variable is undefined or empty in the current shell, it's expansion is the empty string.

To protect a string from "interference" by the shell, use single quotes:

```
$ bash -c 'var=3; echo $var'
+ bash -c 'var=3; echo $var'
3
```

... or escape the `$` (IMO not as nice):

```
$ bash -c "var=3; echo \$var"
+ bash -c 'var=3; echo $var'
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$?` and `$a` are evaluated in the calling shell.

```
bash -c 'cat /tmp/lol ; a=$?; if (( $a == 0)); then echo "2"; fi;'
```

Comment: Why `bash -c "cat /tmp/l3ol ; a=$?; if (( "'$a'" == 0)); then echo '2'; fi;"` prints 2 as well? I dont have `l3ol` file

Comment: Because that evaluates `$?` in the calling shell.

Comment: Oh... I finally get it...